# Can you extend the duration of the "Defend" action?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

The "Defend" action seems to last about 5 seconds, is there a way to increase this?

I'm using the Tinman familiar as a tank so would be useful if it stays defending for longer periods.